# How to disable ' - ; : ~ ` from input and remove from string?

Tags: php

I tried to add extra security by removing special characters. I want to allow letters, numbers and ? = & only.

I tried:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'\'')) {  echo 'true';   }
```

I cannot just simply put ' in between the '' as it breaks it so I tried adding the \ but it didn't work.
Is there a way to detect all the symbols in the url string or input field?

EDIT:

tried adding < simply into the list

```
if (preg_match('#[@*,!$\'\-;:<>~`^|\(\\)\\{\\}\\[\\]]#i', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'script')) { 
    echo 'Cannot do that';
}
```

I tried adding `([\<])([^\>]{1,})*([\>])` into there but it didn't work.
I also tried adding a condition if `strcmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strip_tags($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) != 0`

and when i added  into the url, it didn't do anything

Comment: Why not just handle strings properly?

Comment: extra security for what? What is your script supposed to be used for?

Comment: `str_replace()` if you _really_ need to use it

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I am using pdo prepared statements everywher but for one specific area I have a lot of dynamic values for a search filter so it was hard to use pdo prepared statements so i am trying to somehow do a work around

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have a search filter that takes input from words, radio buttons, and checkboxes. The query length changes constantly so I am not sure how to dynamically make prepared statements to satisfy both the query and the prepared statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_match` to test for anything but the characters you want:

```
if (preg_match('#[^a-z0-9?=&]#i', $str)) { echo 'true'; }
```

Use `preg_replace` to remove them:

```
$str = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9?=&]#i', '', $str);
```

If you just want to prohibit certain characters, use a regular expression that just matches those characters:

```
if (preg_match('#[\'\-;:~`]#i', $str)) { echo 'true'; }
```

Comment: that will replace, how can I check and return true/false?

Comment: BTW, doesn't the URL also include `/` characters?

Comment: Meant to use `i` flag, just forgot it.

Comment: Yes you are right, how can I add /, %, and _? It might be just easier to somehow disable ' - ; : ~ `, is that possible?

Comment: Just add them to the character set in the regular expression. If you're not familiar with regular expressions, read the tutorial at regular-expression.info.

Comment: quick thing, how can I add the symbols < > into the list? I tried \< \<\ <, nothing works..

Comment: There's nothing special about `<` and `>` in regular expressions, you should be able just put them inside the square brackets.

Comment: I did but it didn't work. when I tried adding < to the url nothing happened.

Comment: You'll have to post what you tried. Add it to the end of your question.

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for you. I just copied your regexp, and tested it against `foo<bar`, and it said `Cannot do that`.

Comment: hmm weird.. maybe it's because it's getting the url string not sure why

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the way special characters are encoded in URLs, but I thought that these would have been decoded before filling in `$_SERVER`.

Comment: I just tested, and that's it. Special characters in the URL are %-encoded in REQUEST_URI. Use `urldecode()` to decode it first.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that using double quotes as strings delimiter, try this

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"'")) {  echo 'true';   }
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that none of the posts addressed is why `strpos` didn't work for you. `strpos` can return two types. It can return an integer that is greater than or equal to zero. `0` being the first character. It can also return a boolean type `false`. To check if if strpos found a match it would have to have been written like this:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'\'') !== false) {  echo 'true';   }
```

From the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) The comparison `$a !== $b` operator works this way:

> return TRUE if $a is not equal to $b, or they are not of the same type.

Information on `strpos` returning two types (boolean `false` or an integer) can be found in this [PHP strpos Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). In particular:

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>
> Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.

So as you can see 0 and false are not the same thing which is why your test failed.

As for security and strings in PHP I recommend you look at this StackOverflow [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php) for some opinions on the matter.